# WScript is undefined

Tags: javascript, activex, imagemagick, wsh

I am trying to run a Javascript file locally, which is supposed to create a CSS image sprite using ImageMagick. It's part of the OpenID selector JS component: http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

The generate-sprite.js (http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/source/browse/trunk/generate-sprite.js?r=140) file is supposed to create the image sprite automatically. However, whenever I run it in IE (the local version of the file, of course), I get the error SCRIPT5009: 'WScript' is undefined on line 19, character 1.

I have of course installed ImageMagick and updated the location in the js file. IE9 is letting the ActiveX execute.

Since I'm not familiar with WScript, I am completely lost. Googling didn't help, since this seems to be a very generic error.

Can somebody help diagnose this error please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you're "running" the JavaScript file locally, are you using Windows? If so, and double-clicking or typing the filename from the command line doesn't work, try:

```
wscript generate-sprite.js
```

...which explicitly invokes `wscript.exe`.

If you're not using Windows, you can't use that script — it relies on both Windows and Microsoft's JScript (which the `wscript.exe` program invokes).

Comment: I was including the file in an HTML file and opening that in the browser. I tried wscript generate-sprite.js, but now I'm getting an error on a different line: Line 35, char 1: Expected Identifier, string or number. :(

Comment: The error was on the line 'eval(s)'. I figured it was trying to execute the contents of the other js file, and failing. Instead I just copied the contents into the same file and it worked!